# Python Tkinter binding keys does not work as intended

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I'm filling a `treeview` with text elements and using parent elements to break up the text elements in the `treeview`. Each parent element contains up to 10 text elements as child nodes.

The commands `next_cmd` and `prev_cmd` are used to access the next text element, respectively the previous text element and I want them to highlight the current text element in the `treeview`. And the commands can be accessed by clicking buttons or by pressing the left- respectively the right-arrow-key.

The commands work as intended when the buttons are pressed, but the `prev_cmd` does not work as intended, if you press the left-arrow-key. It just highlights the parent item, but not the child item that contains the current text.
The `next_cmd` strangely works as intended in both cases (both pressing the right arrow key and using the next button).

You can use this minimal example to reproduce the error

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

text = ["Hello", "World", "Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World",
        "Hello", "World", "Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World",
        "Hello", "World", "Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World",
        "Hello", "World", "Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World","Hello", "World"]
text_index = 0

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)

text_preview = ttk.Treeview(mainframe, columns=("text"), show="headings", style="RateFrame.Treeview",
                                selectmode="browse")


def next_cmd(event=None):
    # Works as intended with both using the right-arrow-key as well as pressing the next button.
    global text_index
    global text
    if text_index == len(text) - 1:
        # Do nothing, if end of text was reached.
        return 
    else:
        # Highlight the next child element in the treeview
        text_index = text_index + 1
        child_iid = "child_" + str(text_index)
        text_preview.focus(child_iid)
        text_preview.selection_set(child_iid)

def prev_cmd(event=None):
    # Only pressing the prev-button works as intended, but not using the left-arrow-key.
    global text_index
    global text
    if text_index == 0:
        # Do nothing, if beginning of text was reached.
        return 
    else:
        # Highlight the previous child element in the treeview
        text_index = text_index - 1
        child_iid = "child_" + str(text_index)
        text_preview.focus(child_iid)
        text_preview.selection_set(child_iid)


def populate_treeview():
    upper_limit = math.ceil(len(text) / 10)
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        text_preview.insert("", "end", iid=("parent_" + str(i)), open=False, 
                                values=(("Questions " + str(i * 10 + 1) + " - " + str(len(text))),))

        # Populate the children:
        for j in range(10):
            k = j + 10 * i # Offset k; 0 <= k < len(text)
            if k >= len(text):
                break
            text_preview.insert(("parent_" + str(i)), "end", iid=("child_" + str(k)), open=False,
                                    values=(text[k],))

    # Focus the first child element and open it's parent, when the script starts.
    text_preview.item("parent_0", open=True)
    text_preview.focus("child_0")
    text_preview.selection_set("child_0")
    text_preview.focus_set()

    

text_preview.heading("text", text="Navigation")
text_preview.bind("<Right>", next_cmd)
text_preview.bind("<Left>", prev_cmd)

mainframe.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text_preview.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

prev_btn = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="prev", command=prev_cmd)
next_btn = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="next", command=next_cmd)

prev_btn.pack(side="left")
next_btn.pack(side="right")

populate_treeview()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `left` and `right` keys have default actions for a Treeview widget.  To override these actions, you need to return "break" in the event callback.  However, the `Up` and `Down` keys are already used to do the previous and next function, so I wonder why you need to use `left` and `right` keys. It is not recommended to override such behavior except it is by intention.

Comment: It's by design because I want the SW user to easily switch between different items by clicking the right or left key instead of clicking the button each time.
However, I was able to solve the problem by focusing another frame (using focus_set) with appropriate key bindings, after double-clicking in the Treeview.